# excel vba script wont execute the intended msgbox?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel vba script (below) that I'm having trouble with displaying "match". I set my excel file up with the following information. column A5 to A10 has dates in the format of 3/1/2015, 3/2/2015, etc. (so A5 = 3/1/2015, A6 = 3/2/2015, etc.)

My worksheet has 7 tabs, the first (with the code on it) is the default sheet1. the 2nd through the 7th tab are labeled just as "1" for the 2nd tab, "2", "3", etc to "7". For now I was just testing out A5 to match and display something if it matches tab 2, but isn't working. The commented (out) msgboxes shows that the values should match, but when I try to set an if (they are equal), no bueno. this is a simplified version, so an answer like "why don't you just set the day equal to the day you want" wont work.  Thanks!

```
Sub main()

'MsgBox Day(Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a5").Value)

'MsgBox Worksheets(2).Name

If Day(Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a5").Value) = Worksheets(2).Name Then

MsgBox "match"

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

`Day` function returns an `integer`.

`Worksheets(2).Name` is a `string` property.

To compare those values, you have to convert them to the same type.

```
If CStr(Day(Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a5").Value)) = Worksheets(2).Name Then
```

You can read more about type conversion functions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx)

Comment: thanks! thats what I was thinking, but I wasn't sure. Actually, yesterday I tried to convert both to int, but I think either it didnt' work or I didn't do it right (or both). I'm using the "2" in worksheets(2) in a counter. can I do something like

if day(worksheets("sheet1").range("a5").value)) = Int(worksheets(2).name

instead?

Comment: @JohnDoe Yes, you could also use your version, but my version is more universal. You can convert any `integer` to `string`, and your code will raise `Type mismatch` error if the worksheet name can't be converted to `integer` (like `"sheet1"`)

Comment: works for me! thanks a lot, i've been stuck on this for a few days